# using a viewmodel to assign values from a soap web service to a dropdownlist

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

I need some advice on getting values from a soap web service to display in a dropdownlist using a viewmodel, I currently receive the data for the various dropdownlists from a service class found in a service class library project (n-tier application).

The code for the dropdownlist service follows a similar format to the code below:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getValuesAsSelectItems(string selected)
    {
        var items = new List<SelectListItem>();

        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Please Select", Value = string.Empty, Selected = (selected == string.Empty) });

        foreach (var value in this.getValues())
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = value.Value, Value = value.Value, Selected = (selected == value.Value) });
        }
        return new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text");
    }
```

I need a way of passing the values from this service to the viewmodel I have then created 7 controllers for each of the dropdownlist which will all link to partial views that I can reuse throughout the application, dropdownlists include titles, countries, states  and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach you could take is to extract the drop down list values into a viewmodel of their own. So:

**Step 1:** Create a view model (`ItemsViewModel`) that encapsulates the drop down list items:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Models
{
    public class DropDownListItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemsViewModel
    {
        private readonly List<DropDownListItem> _items;

        // The selected item:
        public string SelectedItem { get; set; }

        // The items:
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items
        {
            get
            {
                var allItems = _items.Select(i => new SelectListItem 
                {
                    Value = i.Value,
                    Text = i.Text
                });
                return DefaultItem.Concat(allItems);
            }
        }

        // Default item (i.e. the "select" text) if none selected
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DefaultItem
        {
            get
            {
                return Enumerable.Repeat(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = "-1",
                    Text = "Select an item"
                }, count: 1);
            }
        }

        public ItemsViewModel()
        {

        }

        // Constructor taking in items from service and selected item string:
        public ItemsViewModel(List<DropDownListItem> items, string selected)
        {
            _items = items;
            SelectedItem = selected;
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Create a partial view in the Views folder that binds to the `ItemsViewModel`:

```
@model Models.ItemsViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem, Model.Items)
```

**Step 3:** In the appropriate controller (e.g. HomeController), place the child action that pulls the data from the service, the view model and the partial view together:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult DropDownList(string type, string selected)
{
    // If you need to call different services based on the type (e.g. Country), then pass through "type" and base the call on that

    var items = new ItemsViewModel(
        (from g in _service.getTitles() select new DropDownListItem { Text = g.Text, Value = g.Value }).ToList(), 
        selected);

    return PartialView("DropDownPartial", items);
}
```

**Step 4:** Drop this line of code into the view where you need the drop down list:

```
@Html.Action("DropDownList", "Home", new { selected = "2", type = "country" })
```

Note that `selected` and `type` are to be determined whichever way you see fit and are optional.

Hopefully this gives you some inspiration.

Comment: thanks for that I have got it working for one service but I am have some difficulty working out how to get it works with a second service so far it works for titles but I am trying to get it to work with a second service for Lead Sources how do I pass this type?

Comment: OK, so the Step 4 bit would look something like `@Html.Action("DropDownList", "Home", new { selected = "2", type = "leadsources" })`. Then in Step 3, you can do something like `if (type == "leadsources")` etc. to call the different service.

Comment: thanks for that, I had used if statements but had the return PartialView outside of the if statement could not access the items variable so have now put the return statement inside of the if is working fine now